# How do I Format string as percentage using converter

Tags: c#, wpf

I'd like to set the property **ContentStringFormat** from a custom converter 
to format some decimals in a DataGrid as percentage.:

```
<Setter Property="ContentStringFormat">
<Setter.Value>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource PercentageConverter}">
        <Binding Path="ItemsSource" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}" />
        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
        <Binding />
    </MultiBinding>
</Setter.Value>
```

I've managed to add my conditions so that the format would only apply for certain cells. But .. I don't know what to return, I have tried `return {0:P2}` but it has no effect:

```
class PercentageConverter
...
   public object Convert(...)
    if (myCustomConditions)
    {
        return "{0:P2}" // how to return my format??
    }
```

What do I need to return to set the ContentStringFormat? Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: I feel like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838691/how-to-display-percent-values-using-contentstringformat) could be helpfull for you.

Comment: Hi maam27, thanks for your reply. The accepted answer there is to set the format in the definition of the DataGridTextColumn. In my case, I do not know the number of columns at design time. And I do not want the format to apply to the whole column, but only to DataGridCells where some conditions are met.

Comment: I think you can add your certain conditions in the AutogeneratingColumn event (using EventTrigger if using MVVM) and set the String format for the particular column. And you can let the other columns as such.

Comment: Hi Karuppasamy, I've used your suggestion before in another scenario, but now I really need to set the format on DataGridCell-level. It's not a whole column that I need to format but only those DataGridCells that meet my conditions.

Comment: I'm asking myself if I did not see something in your link, @maam27, or whether the two upvoters did not notice that the information given in that thread do not provide any answer to my question :o/ ?

Comment: I just gave a link to a similair post where there is an awnser on how to do it to the column, I feel like they upvoted the comment because it is helpfull to people who are trying to set things to percentage. Although it seems that your question requires the code to look for specific cells and not just the entire column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I manipulated the binding source and switched from doubles to strings in the format I wanted. For sorting, I've implemented a custom sorter that converts the strings back to doubles.

Ugly, but beautiful enough for me.

Answer (score -3):

Alternatively you can multiply the value with 100 and append % sign at end and divide by 100 in convert back ..

```
Public Function Convert(ByVal value As Object, ByVal targetType As Type, ByVal parameter As Object, ByVal culture As CultureInfo) As Object Implements IValueConverter.Convert
        If TypeOf value Is Double OrElse TypeOf value Is Decimal Then
            Return value * 100
        Else
            Return 0
        End If
    End Function

    Public Function ConvertBack(ByVal value As Object, ByVal targetType As Type, ByVal parameter As Object, ByVal culture As CultureInfo) As Object Implements IValueConverter.ConvertBack
        If TypeOf value Is Double OrElse TypeOf value Is Decimal Then
            Return value / 100
        Else
            Return 0
        End If
    End Function
```

Comment: ah ?? -1 would care to explain ?